# Why is request.get giving different results from my browser? (webscraping)

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to make a web scraper that collects ads that people have posted on this dutch site that you can use for selling your old stuff.
First, I ask the user for a search_term, a distance and a postal_code.
Then, these three variables are inserted into the URL and the request.get is made. See the function declaration below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl'

def find_ads(BASE_URL, search_term, distance, postal_code):
    new_url = f"{BASE_URL}/q/{search_term}/#distanceMeters:{distance * 1000}|postcode:{postal_code}"
    html_text = requests.get(new_url, timeout=5).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    ads = soup.find_all('li', class_='mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item')

    print(new_url)

    for index, ad in enumerate(ads):
        ad_name = ad.find('h3', class_='mp-Listing-title').text
        ad_location = ad.find('span', class_='mp-Listing-location').text

        print(ad_location + "\n")
        print(ad_name + "\n")

search_term = "bike"
distance = 3
postal_code = 1234ab

find_ads(BASE_URL, search_term, distance, postal_code)
```

The url that is created (new_url) is exactly like I want it. When I copy new_url to my browser, I get the page that I want to scrape, with my location and the distance set.

HOWEVER, when I look at the ad_location, I expect them all to be the city I am in currently, but what I see in my console is random cities scattered across the Netherlands. This means that the page is ignoring my location somehow.

My question: How come requests.gets gets a different result than when I use the same URL in my browser? Why is it ignoring the distance and postal_code I feed into it?

Comment: likely because the page is dynamic and rendered through javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is dynamic. You can get the listings through their api though:

```
import requests

def find_ads(search_term, distance, postal_code):
    url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/lrp/api/search'
    payload = {
            'distanceMeters': '%s' %(distance * 1000),
            'limit': '30',
            'offset': '0',
            'postcode': '%s' %postal_code,
            'query': '%s' %search_term,
            'searchInTitleAndDescription': 'true',
            'viewOptions': 'list-view'}
    
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    
    ads = jsonData['listings']
    for index, ad in enumerate(ads):
        ad_name = ad['title']
        ad_location = ad['location']

        print(ad_location, "\n")
        print(ad_name, "\n")

search_term = "bike"
distance = 3
postal_code = '1234ab'

find_ads(search_term, distance, postal_code)
```

**Output:**

```
{'cityName': 'Dordrecht', 'countryName': 'Nederland', 'countryAbbreviation': 'NL', 'distanceMeters': -1000, 'isBuyerLocation': False, 'onCountryLevel': False, 'abroad': False, 'latitude': 51.811457038595, 'longitude': 4.6650731189384} 

Cortina fietsen de grootste voorraad bij Mega Bike Dordrecht 

{'cityName': 'Dordrecht', 'countryName': 'Nederland', 'countryAbbreviation': 'NL', 'distanceMeters': -1000, 'isBuyerLocation': False, 'onCountryLevel': False, 'abroad': False, 'latitude': 51.811457038595, 'longitude': 4.6650731189384} 

FIETSEN MET LICHTE LAKSCHADE lage prijzen bij Mega Bike 

...
```